# how to get string and return string by async?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have my code as below:

```
    public void getCity()
    {
        ReverseGeocodeQuery reverseGeocode = new ReverseGeocodeQuery();
        reverseGeocode.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(10.79845, 106.65063);
        reverseGeocode.QueryCompleted += reverseGeocode_QueryCompleted;
        reverseGeocode.QueryAsync();
    }

    private void reverseGeocode_QueryCompleted(object sender, QueryCompletedEventArgs<IList<MapLocation>> e)
    {
        MapAddress geoAddress = e.Result[0].Information.Address;
    }
```

I need to get string `Address` at `getCity` method.

But I don't want to handle when query complete to get address. I want get string `Address` at `getCity` method and return address. I think to use async but I don't know how to use.

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're getting the data async, you need to make your method also async. Just return `Task<MapAddress>` and to create a task use `TaskCompletionSource<MapAddress>`.

Here's how you go:

```
public Task<MapAddress> GetCity()
{
    TaskCompletionSource<MapAddress> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<MapAddress>();

    ReverseGeocodeQuery reverseGeocode = new ReverseGeocodeQuery();
    reverseGeocode.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(10.79845, 106.65063);
    reverseGeocode.QueryCompleted += (sender, e)=> tcs.SetResult(e.Result[0].Information.Address);
    reverseGeocode.QueryAsync();

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

You probably need a async method to call this.

```
private async void Something()
{
    MapAddress address = await GetCity();
}
```

Comment: please let me how to get return on Task<MapAddress> GetCity()?I use Task<MapAddress> temp = GetCity(); but it error

Comment: I'm sorry.I mean how to get result on Task<MapAddress> GetCity()?

Comment: It's error at reverseGeocode.QueryCompleted += (sender, e)=> tcs.SetResult(e.Result[0].Information.Address);
 An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in System.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: Post the full exception details, message stack trace, inner exception etc. Edit your question with these details